# How can I determine when a platform event is completed within an aura component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, platform-event

I have an aura component that generates new record.  The helper calls the Apex controller and the records are generated but they are done via a platform event.  How can I determine when the platform event is completed.  I want to get the ids of the new records.

helper

```
var action = component.get("c.submitRecord");   


getJobid: function(component, event, helper, tempId){
         is job created??????
}
```

Controller

```
 @AuraEnabled
    public static String (sObject order, sObject job)
    {

        order__c orders= (orders__c) order;
        job__c jobs = (job__c) job;

        insert orders;

        jobs.order__c = orders.Id; //original code before platform event but received error
        insert jobs;    //original code before platform event but received error
  
      
      Publish_Job__e createJob = new Publish_Job__e();
      createJob.job_JSON__c = jobJSON;
      createJob.job_title__c = 'Title';
      Eventbus.publish(createJob);
```

Comment: Why are we making the record by Platform Event?

Comment: Hey sfdxfox, the first record is parent and second is child.  First record is created using insert job:  If I try to do the same I was getting a cross reference error?  Its been awhile since I did this so can't remember off hand.  Just recall getting an error and creating the child via platform resolved it.

Comment: Is the parent record created directly and synchronously in the server side controller for the Aura component, so allowing the parent record ID to be returned to the component as part of the creation? Could this controller method not simply do a second `insert` statement to insert the child using the parent's ID?

Comment: If you really had to use a platform event (which seems unlikely based on your explanation in comments above) you either have to have the Aura component "poll" to see if the data can be queried fully (using a javascript timer and repeatedly trying to query the parent with child data) or you need to consider using the EMP API/Streaming API - the latter has specific governor limits while the former (I.e. polling) does not.

Comment: I have updated the code to show original syntax before adding the platform event.  Looking at the code again I am thinking maybe the error is because I need to query the newly created order record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the arrangement you have is necessary, I'd use the [lightning:empApi](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:empApi/documentation) library to subscribe to a second Platform Event that could be fired off by the Platform Event trigger to get the data from the child object once it's done.